# How to get param value with jsoup?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm trying to get param value with jsoup but I'm not able to accomplish this.

This is the HTML example:

```
<object id="a5514fbc4f070b58cfbfb2a17ad3011a" name="a5514fbc4f070b58cfbfb2a17ad3011a" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://player.sambatech.com.br/current/2.0.57/profiles/samba/sambaPlayer.swf" width="620" height="410">
<param name="flashvars" value="http://webcast.sambatech.com.br/80479D/origin1/account/143/3/2012-12-14/video/89903bb228d0af488d9dbb1228c3728a/121412AlbertoAcostaSeguridad.mp4">
</object>
```

This is what i have tried so far, but no luck:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(providerUrl).get();
Element p_un = doc.select("param[name=flashvars]").first();
String v = p_un.attr("value");
```

Please I need Help.

Comment: What doesn't work, specifically? You selector looks OK, so I'd double check the output of the get(), and visually make sure that HTML is really in the output of doc.html().

Comment: For some reason its not working. This the [URL](http://www.elcomercio.com/politica/elecciones-presidenciales-alberto-acosta_3_828547150.html) that I'm trying to extract data from. In the HTML source check for "div class=media-obj obj-video" and inside there there is a div that has the object tag with param that im trying to get.

Comment: The page load dinamically the portion of the  html with javascript. You cannot get with Jsoup. :(

Comment: Is there any way with another library i might be able to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can simple access to the value with the [val()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#val%28%29) method.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(providerUrl).get();
// Simple selector. If you wanna get the particular param, 
// change the selector to ("#a5514fbc4f070b58cfbfb2a17ad3011a > param")
Element el = doc.select("param").first();
String value = el.val();
```

Comment: For some reason its not working. This the [URL](http://www.elcomercio.com/politica/elecciones-presidenciales-alberto-acosta_3_828547150.html) that I'm trying to extract data from. In the HTML source check for "div class=media-obj obj-video" and inside there there is a div that has the object tag with param that im trying to get.

Comment: I look in the URL and see that the div with the class 'media-obj obj-video' only contain a script tag, and not a param tag

Comment: That's what i noticed just now. Its weird because when i use 'inspect element' with Chrome the div tag contains the object and param tag but when i use 'view page source' only the script comes up.